# php list inserting blank space formatting issue

Tags: php

I have a list that I would like to break in segments after a date change. Tried inserting lines in several places but i am missing something!

See photo for current and desired. Thanks!

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM m1 
          WHERE mevent='Hiking' AND maffirm='Yes'
          ORDER BY mdate DESC")
          or die(mysql_error());  

echo "<table border='2' cellpadding='10'>";
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
            $currentDate = false;
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                if ($row['mdate'] != $currentDate) {
                    echo '<strong>' . $row['mdate'] . '</strong>' ;
                    $currentDate = $row['mdate'];
                }
                echo '<ul><li>' . $row['mname'] . '</li></ul>'; 
            }  
        echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Current and desired

[image: ivan]

Comment: HI Ivan,yeah I had tried that and it but a blank line between each of the names.

Comment: I post an answer please check and try it and please try to search on google for mysqli or pdo. mysql* is depreched and not securely

Comment: Hi Ivan, I added an new graphic, and comments to you to try and explain where I hope to end up on this project!!

Comment: Not sure what happened to the other comments but trying to get the final product to look like the version on the right. Each date shoeing enough height for all eight members, whether they show up or not. Height important because the table will lay next to a table from another database the same height.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use div with css style. Code below is simple but you can edit easily

```
<style>
    div {
        border: 2px solid #000;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
</style>

<?PHP
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM m1 
      WHERE mevent='Hiking' AND maffirm='Yes'
      ORDER BY mdate DESC")
or die(mysql_error());

echo "<div>";
$currentDate = false;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if ($row['mdate'] != $currentDate){
        echo '<strong>' . $row['mdate'] . '</strong>' ;
        $currentDate = $row['mdate'];
    }
    echo '<ul><li>' . $row['mname'] . '</li></ul>';
}
echo "</div>";

?>
```

Comment: Hi Ivan, I like the idea of using a div instead of the table. Tried your suggestions but returned syntax error with the brace, the third line from the bottom  '}'